# find object by id from nested object list in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a java bean class :

```
class Node{

    int id, parentId;
    String value;
    List<Node> childs;

}
```

How could i find a parent node in this hierarchy and  insert a child node in the child list of parent node.
relationship between to node is defined as :
if `node1.id == node2.parentid` then `node2` will be in child list of `node1`.

This can be Nth level hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find a node in that hierarchy, you'll have to implement a method for traversing.  I suggest using a recursive method and employ either a breadth-first or depth-first search pattern.  Once you've located the correct Node, insert the child.

For instance:

```
public Node search(Node root, int searchId) {
    if (root.id == searchId) {
        return root;
    } else {
        for (Node child : root.childs) {
            Node node = search(child, searchId);
            if (node != null) {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void insert(Node node) {
    Node parent = search(root, node.parentId);
    if (node != null) {
        parent.childs.add(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
insertNode(Node nodeToInsert, Node anyNodeInHirarchy) {
        Node parent = getParentNodeById(anyNodeInHirarchy.parentId);
        if(parent.Id == nodeToInsert.parentId) {
            parent.childs.add(nodeToInsert);
        } else {
            insertNode(nodeToInsert, parent)
        }
    }
    return getParentNodeById(int nodeId) {
        // Find node by id and return
        return node;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

easily :

```
childNode.setParentId(parentNode.getId());
parentNode.getChilds().add(childNode);
```

Comment: i have to insert a node at its parent child list. for that i have to find parent for a node (if exists) . i want that searching mechanism to find the parent

Comment: I have an example of a search algorithm in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fast way of doing it is 
Guid should point the object easily so that you can point nth node easily.

Generate  a Single Random GUID
for eg : say 45892
Root node will point to that id.
child will point in the pattern Parent_ID+"-"+Index_Number
If consider three child  will have 45892-0, 45892-1, 45892-2
And child of first node becomes - 45892-0-1, 45892-0-2

So you can travel directly using the id as faster and need not search, search time will be saved.

If you don't understand please comment. I will show in programming.

Note : ID length grows as depends on your level of usage.

If you have data already in the db or some persistent store.then you can prefer jgitter code. if not you can prefer this.

```
     class Node {
                public String id;
                public String parentId;
                public List<Node> childs;

            } 

            class Operation {
                public Node getChildNodeByID(Node root,String parentId) {
                    String[] keys = parentId.split("-");
                    Node parentNode = root;
                    int index = 0;
                    for(String key : keys ) {     
                        if(index == 0) {
                            if( !root.id.equals(key) ) {
                               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Root node does not match so parent node will not be found in this node");
                            }
                        }else {
                            int myIndex = Integer.parseInt(key);
                            if( parentNode.childs.getSize() > myIndex ) {
                                parentNode = parentNode.childs.get(myIndex);
                            }else {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parent Node does not exist");
                            }
                        }   
                        index++;
                    }
return parentNode;
                }

              public insert(Node node,Node root) {
                   Node parentNode =  getChildNodeByID(root,node.parentId);                  
                   node.id = node.parentId+"-"+parentNode.childs.getSize();
                   parentNode.childs.add(node);  
              }
            }
```

Comment: I fail to see how this negates the need for a search in a N-level tree with M children on each node.

Comment: Split the GUID by '-' now it will first will point to the root node and from second all the items will follow the index in the array.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to iterate through all of the nodes to find the correct id.  You've changed the algorithm, but the search is still there.

Comment: He's talking about setting up an index with a GUID to Node mapping so you can get to a Node without search.  Problem is, you would have to change your integer ids to match his scheme or you'll still have to iterate through the nodes.  I have an example of a recursive depth first search implemented above.

Comment: Note : if the index is out of range then the node does not exist.

Comment: Yes, It has to be iterated but does not required the full search on all the nodes in the tree, only traversal to the corresponding node and it will be of O(n). where n is level.